# C# Performance issue about List<T> Count property

Tags: c#, performance

The project I am working on is about request a xml from a web set. The server side construct the xml. The xml may have many nodes, so the performance is not that good.

I use virtual studio 2010 profiler to analyze the performance issue.
Find out that the most time-consuming function is **System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1.get_Count()** which actually is Count property of Generic List.This function is called about **9000 times**.

The performance data shown as below:

The **Elapsed exclusive time** is **4154.14(ms)**, while the **Application exclusive time** is just **0.52(ms)**.

I know the different between Elapsed exclusive time and Application exclusive time.
Application exclusive time exclude the time spend on the context switch stuff. 
How could context switch stuff happy when the code just obtain the Count property of the Generic List.

I am very confused by the performance profiler data. Is anyone can provide some information? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show some of the code and some profiler results. This does not seem right. At this point, you can't receive good answers.

Comment: In your question you refer to `ICollection.Count` How do you know that is `List<T>` and not some other collection?

Comment: could you show some code ?

Comment: This isn't possible.  Don't profile the Debug build of your program.  Focus on how much time is spent on garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the decompiled sources show the following for `List<T>`:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public int Count
{
  [__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")] get
  {
    return this._size;
  }
}
```

It's literally returning the value of a field and doing nothing else. I'd suggest your performance hit is elsewhere, or you're misinterpreting your profiler's output.

Comment: Thanks Nathan Ridley, But I am sure that I do not misinterpreting the profiler's output.

Comment: ... the decompiled source is pretty explicit in what it does.

Comment: @user2947351, Count has nothing to do with performance hit, it is the method that calling Count is expensive.